# Symfony Controller return array

Tags: symfony, controller, response, symfony-2.8

I am trying to create a listener that configures the `Response` using annotations and sets the response content as the controller return.

The Controller code:

```
use PmtVct\PhotoBookBundle\Annotations\ResponseType;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

/**
* @ResponseType("JSON")
*/
public function home(Request $request) {
    return ['asdf' => 123];
}
```

But I receive the '`The controller must return a response`' error.

There is a way to return an array on `Controller` instead a `Response`?

Comment: And the array would then go to the listener?

Comment: yes, and the listener will define which response type(JsonResponse, Response) to use

Comment: Okay.  Store your data in the request object with: $request->attributes->set('data',[whatever]); and then just return null from the controller.  Have your view listener pull the data from the request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to do a similar thing to [FOSRestBundle](http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSRestBundle/index.html). Maybe consider using this bundle? It will allow:

- Return arrays in controller, exactly in a way you want
- Serialise response into Json, or other format you wish, also it can detect format automatically from Request.

**In case you still want to build such listener yourself** - look how it's done in FOSRestBundle - https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle/blob/master/EventListener/ViewResponseListener.php - they are using "kernel.view" event.

Answer (score 1):

Explain https://stackoverflow.com/a/46007749/21333278:

Controller:

```php
class YourController extends AbstractController
{
    #[Route('your/route', methods: ['GET'])]
    public function __invoke(): YourRouteResponseDTO
    {
        return new YourRouteResponseDTO();
    }
}
```

Instead of YourRouteResponseDTO class, you can use an array, but the more typing, the better.

```php
class YourRouteResponseDTO implements ResponseJsonInterface
{
    public int $param1;
    public YourAnotherResponseDTO $param2;
}
```

And listener

```php
namespace App\Listener;

use App\Contract\ResponseJsonInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\ViewEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\SerializerInterface;

class ResponseListener
{
    public function __construct(
        private readonly SerializerInterface $serializer,
    ) {
    }

    public function __invoke(ViewEvent $event): void
    {
        $response = $event->getControllerResult();
        if (!($response instanceof ResponseJsonInterface)) {
            return;
        }
        $jsonResponse = $this->json($response);

        $event->setResponse($jsonResponse);
    }

    protected function json(mixed $data, int $status = 200, array $headers = [], array $context = []): JsonResponse
    {
        $json = $this->serializer->serialize($data, 'json', array_merge([
            'json_encode_options' => JsonResponse::DEFAULT_ENCODING_OPTIONS
                | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE
                | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES
                | JSON_PRETTY_PRINT,
        ], $context));

        return new JsonResponse($json, $status, $headers, true);
    }
}
```

```yaml
#services.yaml
services
    App\Listener\ResponseListener:
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.view, priority: 10 }
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation.html#creating-a-json-response) you can return a JsonResponse like this:

```
return new JsonResponse(['asdf' => 123]);
```

Comment: I don't want to add the response on controller, but outside in the Listener.

Comment: Why would you need a listener to create a json response? Also can you share your listener code if you have any? I'm not quite sure about what you want to do.

Comment: I need to create the response outside of the controller for making the development of a new controller more agile. In my idea, i send the response type in an annotation and return just the needed data in the function. Instead of `public function home(Request $request) {
    $response = new Response(['asdf' => 123]);
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');}` will be `/**
* @ResponseType("JSON")
*/
public function home(Request $request) {
    return ['asdf' => 123];
}`

Comment: Documentation says : "The JsonResponse class sets the Content-Type header to application/json and encodes your data to JSON when needed."

You don't even need to set the header content type yourself if you use a `JsonResponse`. And if by "agile" you mean simple or flexible I think using a `JsonResponse` is the best way for that. You don't even need to add an annotation or use a listener.